# How to display only filtered data range in data validation rule in Google sheet

Tags: validation, google-sheets, filter, dropdown, formula

I have a table with two sheets. The first (Records) records the players from the form and a filter is performed here to determine the team (1 or 2 or 3) also.

The second table (Players) will perform calculations for individual players (one row for one  player). In the first column, I will select a player using a dropdown. The problem is that all players are in the dropdown. I need the filtered ones (eg team 1 and 3). Can anyone help me? Thanks

[Example sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zjAYoUCEIf85zP3Q8o6PCG_NZAGXxatbltDn2dlsrLE/edit#gid=0)

Update:
I'll apply a filter to the team first. E.g. 1 and 2 in the Records table.
Then select the winner in the Players sheet (from the filtered list 1 and 2), then select the loser from the same filtered list, but there will not be the player I just selected as the winner.
[image]

Comment: Data filters and hidden rows are only visual features. Formulas ignore them and will always see the values in your hidden cells as if they were visible.

Comment: What is the end goal of the filters and calculations? To have one player of each time vs another from another team?

Comment: I updated my post. Take a look, please.

Comment: Do the players play many games? Because if they only play one, you could set a 1 for the winners and a 0 for the losers and filter from that

Comment: Yes they play many games (even repetitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUBTOTAL(103; C2)
```

[image]

```
=FILTER(Records!D2:D; Records!F2:F=1)
```

[image]

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RWu_gLHpyda6oIkXMiCcjpNJqlGvu5pgyxA8_YJ2J9M/copy)

Comment: Thanks for the advice with dropdowns, it works perfectly. I have one more question. How to choose the player who lost. It will be from the same list, but I cannot select the same player who won.

The sample table is updated

Comment: @PetrS try: `=FILTER(Records!D2:D; Records!E2:E=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `filter()` function where you create a dynamic dropdown based on the team number you select. I have included an example where you can select a combo of a few team numbers together. If you choose only team 1 and leave the other two dropdowns blank (yellow), it will only show the names from team 1.

**[Dynamic Dropdown Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sVoZptYqmRbO5xj_gnir1gxmiA32CsdJ0fq40a8k7-s/edit#gid=61613697)**

[image]

[image]